# Sending a text string through PHP exec()

Tags: php, exec

I have a base64 image string that I am trying to pass to a C++ function through PHP exec(). But if there are spaces inside a string exec() does not work.

```
$data="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAImCAMAAACSFogBAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c";
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
exec('./hello'.$data, $out,$return);
if(!$return)
{
echo 'created';
}

else
{
echo 'not created';
}
```

Comment: If there is no space between `'./hello'.$data` it wont work as it wont be passed as a param just a massive filename. Also why not just `str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $str) `instead?

Comment: So change the exec line:  `exec("./hello $data",$out,$return);`   Notice the space after hello.

Comment: Your question is what?  What if there are spaces inside $data ?

Comment: You may also want to check its an image else command injection is easily done with a crafted string like: `data:image/png;base64,MA== | rm -rf ../`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$data = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $data);
exec('"./hello'.$data.'"', $out, $return);
```

instead of just the exec method.

P.S.: I'm not sure whether the replace is needed or not if all the command is in double quotes, try with the replace and without it.